# flutter floating action button layout (Android)

Tags: android, flutter, mobile, floating-action-button

is it possible that to show flutter action button like below layout (second picture when it gets open) ? I have tried speed dial or try to create custom layout as well but not able to achieve the second picture layout. Is there any way to achieve this ?

Comment: expandable fab with customShape

Answer (score 2):

**To make layout in first image**

```
Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        floatingActionButton: floatingBtn(context),
        bottomNavigationBar: bottomNavigationBar(context),
        floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      )
```

*Note : I have just provided main properties you can design widgets as you wants*

Here is BottomAppBar Code

```
BottomAppBar(
        notchMargin: 11,
        surfaceTintColor: Colors.red,
        shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            
          ],
        ),
      )
```

**For Design in second Image**
[You can use any plugin from here](https://fluttergems.dev/floating-action-button/)
Or you can create a custom floating action button here is an [example for custom  fab](https://medium.com/@agungsurya/create-a-simple-animated-floatingactionbutton-in-flutter-2d24f37cfbcc)